# Why does my NSWindow only receive mouseOver events the first time?

Tags: cocoa, mouseover, nswindow, first-responder, makekeyandordertofront

I have an application where a borderless window is shown and hidden, using orderOut and orderFront. When it is visible, I want the it to become the key window when the mouse moves over it.
So far I've done this:

- In awakeFromNib I have set its first responder to itself.
- In the window's constructor I set accepts mouse events to YES.
- In the mouseMoved method, I use makeKeyAndOrderToFront.

My problem is, that this only works the first time I move the mouse over the window.
After that, it doesn't receive any mouseOver events.
I've tried checking the firstResponder but as far as I can tell it never changes from the window.

Any ideas what I can do to get this working?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a [tracking area](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSTrackingArea_class/Reference/Reference.html) if you want to receive `mouseMoved` events (I assume that's what you mean as Cocoa has no such thing as a `mouseOver` event).

I wrote a little app called Shroud which does something similar — it hides a borderless window which covers the menu bar when you move the mouse over it.  The [code](http://github.com/nriley/Shroud/) is simple enough it might be useful as an example.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example written with the help of [@NicholasRiley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6372/nicholas-riley)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846205/2108547):

```
NSTrackingArea *area = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self.view frame] options:NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingInVisibleRect | NSTrackingActiveAlways owner:self userInfo:nil];
[self.view addTrackingArea:area];

-(void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSLog(@"mouseEntered");
}

-(void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSLog(@"mouseExited");
}
```